# Web API fails to prompt for Windows credentials when a MVC view does

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest, windows-authentication

I have a windows authentication (only) enabled for a .net core MVC app.  I have One controller returns a standard MVC (VIEW) and another controller (API) returns json.  Requests for a view properly requests for credentials (which are smart-cards) and returns the expected result.  Requests to the API prompts for credentials only when called from the browser address bar directly but fails part of a xmlhttprequest (401-unauthorized).  If, however, a call to the view is successful, the call to the xmlhttprequest also succeeds until the browser cache is cleared or the session is closed.  I need to have the xmlhttprequest prompt for credentials without loading a view.  I have had a work around by including a hidden IFrame that loads a view and, upon a successful load, make xmlhttprequest calls.  This works but is a lot of overhead.  I feel like I am missing something simple but cannot figure it out.

Comment: please share relevant code

Comment: web api should not prompt anything. Web API should be dumb and just return status codes based upon user request. Therefore in your case it should be the responsibility of mvc view only to ask for credentuals based upon the response received from the web api

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I still need a mechanism to pass smart-card credentials to the Web-API to authenticate against Active Directory without calling any MVC view.  It works if the API is pasted into the browser address bar but not from an xmlhttprequest.